# Why is .gitignore not ignoring my files?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

See the image below. My .gitignore file should be ignoring all files in src/dist, but isn't.

[image]

Comment: If you already added those files and `git` is tracking them,  the `.gitignore` file has no effect because it is meant for untracked files. See a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673910/2430526

Comment: Another good option for ignoring already tracked files: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241145/7569365

Answer (score 919, accepted):

`.gitignore` only ignores files that are not part of the repository yet.  If you already `git add`ed some files, their changes will still be tracked.
To remove those files from your repository (but not from your file system) use `git rm --cached` on them.

Comment: git rm --cached file_name.ext wroks fine for me to update gitignore for one file. thanks.

Comment: I did this, but GitHub still wants to track and add them.

Comment: git rm -r --cached folder to recursively remove the cache on a folder

Comment: Ignoring the files didn't work for me but I ignored the dist folder like Pablo mentioned and it worked beautifully!

Comment: @sybozz and with the beauty of bash pattern globbing (using the * character) it works for lots of files too.

Comment: i am using "git rm --cached" and it is returning information - usage: git rm [<options>] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched

Comment: But, this shows that the file node is deleted and when I pushed my changes after executing this command, the file in the server got deleted :( . Did anyone else face this issue ?

Comment: This did not work for me, but I noticed that my file had already been staged. Removing it via `git restore --staged <file>` did the trick!

Comment: In case of error on applying command, use --force, -f before the file name that resolves the case!!!

Comment: User `.` for current working directory or specify another directory for successful execution

Comment: finally some one explains this like a human

Comment: This removes files from the file system too when I sync the current branch with another.

Answer (score 432):

The `.gitignore` file ensures that files not tracked by `Git` remain untracked.

Just adding folders/files to a `.gitignore` file will not untrack them -- they will remain tracked by `Git`.

To untrack files, it is necessary to remove from the repository the tracked files listed in `.gitignore` file. Then re-add them and commit your changes.

The easiest, most thorough way to do this is to remove and cache all files in the repository, then add them all back. All folders/files listed in `.gitignore` file will not be tracked. From the top folder in the repository run the following commands:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

Then commit your changes:

```
git commit -m "Untrack files in .gitignore"
```

Please note that any previous commits with the unwanted files will remain in the commit history. When pushing to GitHub be aware of a commit history that might contain `.env` or `client_secret.json` files.

**Best practice** is to create a .gitignore file and populate it with the folders/files you do not want tracked when starting a project. However, often it is necessary to add to the `.gitignore` file after realising that unwanted files are being tracked and stored.

Comment: thank you for the answer. This really helped. Don't forget to push the repo up to git either

Comment: After using `git rm -r --cached .` rolling back all changes also works to re-add all of the files that should not be excluded with _.gitignore_.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: This is the more complete answer

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Doing this lists every file in our repo as modified and wants to commit everything :(
Even though none of the files have changed, git is considering them modified. Why is this?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I needed extra explanation of how it's necessary to run a git commit -m "..." after git rm -r  --cached

Comment: As a side note, in GitHub Desktop, when you have a project in a directory that you want to upload for the first time, and a .gitignore file it with a proper spec of what you want to exclude, DO NOT select the gitignore option in GitHub Desktop, as it will overwrite your own.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 50):

You can use this,

```
git rm -r --cached ./node_modules
```

if you want to ignore node_modules, for example

Answer (score 36):

`gitignore` ignores only untracked files. Your files are marked as modified - meaning they were committed in the past, and git now tracks them.

To ignore them, you first need to delete them, `git rm` them, commit and then ignore them.

Answer (score 31):

first check the `.gitignore` encoding.
make sure the encoding id `utf-8`.
then untracked unwanted file by using `git rm --cached filename`
now your problem fixed

Comment: The file reencoding did it for me.

Comment: +1 ... Created my .gitignore via 'touch' in MINGW64 shell and didn't notice that the encoding was NOT utf-8 (had .gitignore already open in Notepad++ so checking and changing encoding was easy).  Wish I had googled earlier.

Comment: It removes the file completely from tracking, it might not work in case you still want to keep & track the file in a default state and ignore any further changes to it.

Answer (score 9):

Look at this : [.gitignore is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working)
And particularly the remark from ADTC:

> Make sure your .gitignore file uses ANSI or UTF-8 encoding. If it uses
>   something else like Unicode BOM, it's possible that Git can't read the
>   file. – ADTC Dec 14 '17 at 12:39

Answer (score 7):

**If you are using VS Code**:

Check the `.gitignore` file's Encoding Type. Change it to `UTF-8` if it is not.
Select the `Reopen with Encoding` option to change the file encoding.

This worked for me!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use this :

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>

For start tracking changes again run the following command:

git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use these commands:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For some of the files in my project I needed to use `git filter-branch` which is better explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25458504/14039999) answare.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create .gitignore file in starting and mentioning the files we want to be ignored.
If you want to ignore some files then execute git `rm -r --cached`

Comment: Sometimes, we need a time machine ...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and then I realized that I had not created the .gitignore file properly.

In my case for some reason I created a .gitignore.txt file. Git will still track the files in the .gitignore file even after you remove the '.txt'. extension and save it.

Try deleting your old file and creating a new .gitignore file by `'touch .gitignore'` in terminal, which solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above solutions didn't work, please try this.

The target files which you want to ignore should not be in staging area. Please double check it.

Answer (score -1):

First delete the index.lock file from your git repo

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

and then add .gitignore

```
git add .gitignore
```

Comment: Can you please elobrate what these action does?