# GitFlow wants to add .vs directory in a new feature branch and crash because of that

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-flow

I've created a new feature branch from develop and made some changes in it.
When I try to first validate my branch (I'm not sure if it's adding or commiting), I see the.vs folder in the list of files. Then I get a fatal error (see picture below)

[image: View of files to validate and the fatal error]

I've tried to close visual studio, delete that damned folder and open VS again : there is a little change : the files are now shown as strikeout text, but I get the same error.

I've tried to clear the cache but no effect on my issue :

```
$ git rm -r --cached
```

I've looked on Gitlab my master branch and I don't see the vs folder.
EDIT : but it's present on my develop branch (I never use this branch but I gues I have the same git issue on it)

Of course .vs folder is into my gitignore...

Please help me, I am completely stuck... How can I removed that folder from Git in this feature branch and in the develop branch without losing the changes I've made in feature branch ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution in that post : [Why is .gitignore not ignoring my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400361/why-is-gitignore-not-ignoring-my-files)

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

Then I open VS and i am able to remove the .vs folder from the list with the Git option "not indexing"

Then I removed the .vs folder in my feature branch (and in my develop branch) thanks to that post : https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-to-delete-multiples-files-in-Github/td-p/4623