# .gitignore not ignoring files and folders listed

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-bash

so I wanted my .gitignore to ignore: /vendor #vendor folder composer.lock but when I git add and commit and even push, the file and folder still remains on git i even added another dir just to confirm , it does not still work

Comment: Hello Daniel,
Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53431148/10751129

Comment: show the .gitignore file

Comment: it did .. thanks a lot