# The Library and Logs folder appear, although there is a .gitignore file

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, gitignore, github-desktop

I add .gitignore file in my project. When I open the project on GitHub Desktop, I see some changes. Like this;

[GitHub Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS4w1.png)

Why I see this changes. I dont changing these.

This is my .gitignore file;

[.gitignore code](https://www.codepile.net/pile/ObdoKKDv)

Comment: Try to avoid using images if text will do (e.g., copy-paste the *contents* of the `.gitignore` file, don't use a link). See [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is .gitignore not ignoring my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400361/why-is-gitignore-not-ignoring-my-files)

Answer (score 0):

`gitignore` ignores only untracked files. Your files are marked as modified - meaning they were committed in the past, and git now tracks them. To ignore them, you first need to delete them, git rm them, commit and then ignore them.