# Why isn't my global .gitignore file being picked up in GitBash on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, gitignore

I'm using GitBash  (minitty 3.6.4)on Windows 10.  I have this version of Git installed

```
$ git -v
git version 2.41.0.windows.1
```

I have this global .gitignore file set up

```
$ cat ~/.gitignore
*.bak
```

However, when I go to commit files on the Git command line, I still see my file with the extension

```
$ git status
...
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    src/main/resources/props/my.properties.bak

no changes added to comit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What else do I need to do to have my file ignored in GitBash on Windows?

**Edit:** Adding the check-ignore command output ...

```
$ git check-ignore -v -- src/main/resources/props/my.properties.bak
.gitignore:4:!**/src/main/resources/props/my.properties.bak
```

Comment: You need to [configure `core.excludesFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore).

Comment: I tried entering "git config --global core.excludesFile '~/.gitignore'" and then restarted my GitBash shell, but it is still reporting my file with untracked files when I do "git status".

Comment: Have you tried full path instead of `~/...`?

Comment: Yes, gave that a go but no dice.

Comment: "git config --global core.excludesFile ~/.gitignore" - try making it without quotes around `~/.gitignore`

Comment: UPD: hm.. both ways actually work.

Comment: Could it be that rules are overridden locally with something like `!*` or `!*.bak`?

Comment: Not sure.  How would I check/test that?

Comment: @Dave With the `git check-ignore` command I mention in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77198324/6309): it will tell you which `.gitignore`/exclude` file is ignoring your file (empty output means: the file is not ignored, possibly because it is in a nested Git repository, or it was already tracked -- added+committed -- by Git)

Comment: @Dave I think you need to remove the file from Git's tracking : `git rm --cached src/main/resources/props/my.properties.bak`

Comment: what's in your `.git/info/exclude` file? (it's possible that your exclude file includes .gitignore x.x)

Comment: Please follow this StackOverflow answer in order to configure the global git ignore file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7335487/10721627

Answer (score 1):

For testing, I would add a `.gitignore` at the root folder of your repository, instead of `~` (`/home/me`, which should not be a repository)

Then I would check the output of:

```
git check-ignore -v -- src/main/resources/props/my.properties.bak
```

Check also for any `.git/` subfolder in `src`, `src/main`, `src/main/resources`, ...: any nested repository, with its own `.gitignore`, could override the `core.excludesFile` one.

---

> ```
> $ git check-ignore -v -- src/main/resources/props/my.properties.bak
> .gitignore:4:!**/src/main/resources/props/my.properties.bak
> ```

That would explain why that `.bak` file is not ignored.

> Unfortunately, it is not an option to alter the "`.gitignore`" file of the repository. My change needs to be something specific to my setup that doesn't get checked in.

Then your actual `my.properties` file should remain private (not tracked by Git).
You should only track a `my.properties` file template

```
  my.properties.ini.tpl
```

Then, you can use a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

A "smudge script" creates the right `my.properties` file by using the template, or leave the existing `my.properties` untouched if it was already created.

See a content driver setup example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".

Your `.gitattributes` would include `my.properties.ini.tpl filter=smudgeScript`

```bash
git config filter.smudgeScript.smudge /path/to/your/smudgeScript
git config filter.smudgeScript.clean "cat my.properties.ini.tpl"
```

With `smudgeScript`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the path of your template and actual file
TEMPLATE_PATH="src/main/resources/props/my.properties.ini.tpl"
ACTUAL_PATH="src/main/resources/props/my.properties"

# Check if the actual file already exists
if [[ -f $ACTUAL_PATH ]]; then
  # If the actual file exists, leave it untouched
  cat $ACTUAL_PATH
else
  # Otherwise, create it based on the template
  cat $TEMPLATE_PATH
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not an option to alter the ".gitignore" file of the repository.  My change needs to be something specific to my setup that doesn't get checked in.  Also, I edited my question to include theoutput of the "check-ignore" command.

Comment: @Dave OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I don't know as I'm totally grasping your solution.  I want to globally ignore all files with a "*.bak" extension.  I have in my example a "my.properties.bak" and if I create a "MyClass.java.bak" file, this also does not get ignored.

Comment: @Dave Do a `git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/MyClass.java.bak` and you will see why this file is not ignored. My answer is about your sentence: "My change needs to be something specific to my setup that doesn't get checked in". A content driver is the answer for that use case.

Comment: I'm a little slow -- you said in your answer with regards to "git check-ignore", "That would explain why that .bak file is not ignored." but I'm not understanding.  You're saying something in my repositories ".gitignore" file is causing the *.bak files not to get ignored?

Comment: @Dave If it is *not* ignored, then `git rm --cached -- /path/to/MyClass.java.bak`, then check if it is ignored (now that it is no longer tracked by Git) with `git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/MyClass.java.bak`

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same scenario couple of days ago, and for me the answer was that git ignores only files that aren't already part of the repo.

Full answer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400404/3059536) (maybe we should dupe them if it's the same problem?).

`.gitignore` only ignores files that are not part of the repository yet. If you already git added some files, their changes will still be tracked. To remove those files from your repository (but not from your file system) use `git rm --cached` on them.