# The folder "obj\Debug\net7.0" keeps causing conflicts whenever I try to merge branches

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, git, github

whenever I checkout to another branch it seems like certain folders, such as "obj\Debug\net7.0", always seemed to get modified somehow, particularly after I stage, commit, and push the branch.

As a result, whenever I try to merge branches, I always get merge conflicts.

I am fairly new to Git and to C# ASP.NET, so I am unsure whether its safe to delete this file (if someone can help me with this question too, I'll be grateful).
I am not sure how to fix this issue which I face repeatedly, and I cannot seem to find and answer.

Here is a screenshot from Visual Studio's "Git Changes" window which shows the folder which keeps getting modified by itself:

Screenshot of Visual Studio "Git Changes":

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio "Git Changes"]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The obj and bin folders should be ignored by source control. You can setup files and folder to ignore using a gitignore file ... https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: The `obj` (and `bin`) folder absolutely should not be committed to source control.  Just remove it entirely.

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. After searching through the project folders I found a couple of issues... Firstly, the .gitignore file already existed, but it was inside the project folder, which leads to my second point. The second point was that git was initialised in the project's parent folder AND the project's folder itself. So I deleted the .git files of the parent folder, so now I was only using the project's folder on Visual Studio for git, so now the .gitignore worked, although I had to refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400361/why-is-gitignore-not-ignoring-my-files